# Einstein and the existence of Black Holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities

I have seen some papers claiming that Einstein said there is no Black Hole in the real world, here is a phrase from Einstein himself, see [this arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0412058v1):

> The basic result of study is the distinct understanding that there are no
>   Schwarzschild singularities in the real world. Thought the offered theory considers only such systems, in which particles move by circle trajectories, we have to hardly doubt that the investigation of generic case will lead to the same results. The Schwarzschild singularity is absent, because the matter cannot concentrated in an arbitrary way;otherwise particles composing the clump will reach the speed of light.

Why did Einstein say the particles composing the clump will reach the speed of light? And why haven't other physicists accepted his argument?

Comment: Note that Einstein died *before* any of the now-standard cosmological datasets were gathered, depriving him of a ton of knowledge!

Comment: As a note, Einstein apparently said this in 1939. Back then, we were somewhat lacking in the experimental search (or lack of it) for black holes!

Comment: There is also another good paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0601

Comment: The preprint you cite seems to display some basic misunderstandings about GR

Comment: What misunderstandings?, however This is not the only paper, look at Abhas Mitra [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0601) on the subject, he has also supported the preprint that i cited in his numerous works, also look at [this](http://www.science20.com/eternal_blogs/blog/do_trapped_surfaces_penrose_hawking_ever_form-85630), [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=75825) also would be a good discussion,

Comment: @Amirpouyan The definition of velocity they use in this article is wrong. Einstein was studying clouds of dust and their possible collapses and found out that it is not so easy to form a black hole, which might be the case they cite in this article (they do not even cite properly, this is not really a scientific article). However, later theoretical studies confirmed black hole formation (see Holographer's answer) and the results were further strengthened by [quasar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) observations in the sixties and their effective black-hole models.

Comment: Note that other big names in the field were also hesitant to accept black holes. See Wikipedia's [history of the Chandrasekhar limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit#History) for how Eddington convinced everyone Chandrasekhar's argument must somehow be wrong.

Comment: Void: would you mind explaining why their definition of velocity is wrong? because it seems that they are using D.Hilbert works,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Understandably, Einstein would probably have been uncomfortable with the idea of singularities being consequences of GR. Your quote seems to indicate that he thought the singularity of a Schwarzschild solution was an accident caused by exact spherically symmetry, and that a more generic configuration would somehow not result in a singularity at all. However, his arguments are no more that heuristics and intuition. In such extreme circumstances, anyone's intuition is likely to be challenged. In the end you have to do the work to find out the real consequences of the theory!

The status of this was made clear when it was later proved by Hawking and Penrose that in some quite general circumstances, formation of a singularity is in fact completely inevitable in classical GR and related theories. (Read more at [Hawking-Penrose singularity theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems)).

Any denial of the formation of singularities must make some modification to the assumptions of the proof: some exotic matter, for example.

Comment: [Here](http://www.science20.com/eternal_blogs/blog/do_trapped_surfaces_penrose_hawking_ever_form-85630) is a good discussion about singularity theorems, i guess Abhas Mitra has answered the issues regarding the singularity theorems, just look at his numerous papers on arxiv about this subject, also check [his wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhas_Mitra)

Comment: It seems that everyone thinks inside the mainstream Black Hole research, okee dokee ... maybe because it is the right path ... or maybe ...